# Get online players data via battle.net API

Tags: world-of-warcraft, battlenet-api

Can I get battle.net player data in my web app via API?
I am particularly interested in who is online!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the WoW Character Profile API at https://dev.battle.net/io-docs, the only call that might return whether someone is online is FEED, which returns "The activity feed of the character."  I suspect this does not return the online status, but cannot confirm as I don't have an API key.